# Combine two docker images to prevent docker inside docker

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, server

I've got a nodejs server inside docker:

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app

RUN yarn install

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

And then I've got a dockerfile that is used for converting 3D models:

```
FROM leon/usd:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/ufg

# Configuration
ARG UFG_RELEASE="3bf441e0eb5b6cfbe487bbf1e2b42b7447c43d02"
ARG UFG_SRC="/usr/src/ufg"
ARG UFG_INSTALL="/usr/local/ufg"
ENV USD_DIR="/usr/local/usd"
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${USD_DIR}/lib:${UFG_SRC}/lib"
ENV PATH="${PATH}:${UFG_INSTALL}/bin"
ENV PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:${UFG_INSTALL}/python"

# Build + install usd_from_gltf
RUN git init && \
    git remote add origin https://github.com/google/usd_from_gltf.git && \
    git fetch --depth 1 origin "${UFG_RELEASE}" && \
    git checkout FETCH_HEAD && \
    python "${UFG_SRC}/tools/ufginstall/ufginstall.py" -v "${UFG_INSTALL}" "${USD_DIR}" && \
    cp -r "${UFG_SRC}/tools/ufgbatch" "${UFG_INSTALL}/python" && \
    rm -rf "${UFG_SRC}" "${UFG_INSTALL}/build" "${UFG_INSTALL}/src"

RUN mkdir /usr/app
WORKDIR /usr/app
# Start the service

ENTRYPOINT ["usd_from_gltf"]
CMD ["usd_from_gltf"]
```

The image works like so: When run, the 3d model passed as an argument is converted and then the image stops running

I want to have my node.js server running all the time, and when there's a request for conversion, the second image converts the file. I don't really care whether the second image runs on request, or runs all the time.

How can I do this?

Comment: One possibility is to install a docker cli inside your node container and then mount the docker socker `/var/run/docker.sock` in that container so it can run your other container. However it is a bad practice to mount the docker socket since there are some security issues.

Comment: Then you can check what's inside the `leon/usd:latest` Dockerfile to copy what's needed and your second Dockerfile in your first one.

Comment: But that doesn't solve the problem at all